# Request Timing in `$.ajax` is sometimes above 1 second and sometimes 30ms

Tags: ajax, apache, xampp, response, delayed-execution

I am using xampp version 1.7.7 on windows 7. I am trying to do that when you click save image it would send information to save_record.php in the background. I do this with

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'save_record.php',
      data: values.join("&"),
      success: function(data) {
            //document.write(data);
          }
    });
```

And it is clearly not the issue. The problem is that the response is very slow and I am unable to find the reason for it. Below I add the data I received from chrome speed tracer. Firebug is also showing all responses above 1 second. They come in format like 1055ms or 1035ms which makes me think it gets stuck somewhere for one second. If that was not weird enough, it starts making the requests fast (30-50ms) at some time and that is a perfectly usable application for me. Otherwise that 1 second delay is killing it. I once killed process explorer.exe and added as a new task and it worked. But the next time it didn't. I restarted the pc - it is one second... And while I was typing this question it started doing those fast requests. Once it starts doing them fast it's all good, but when I start xampp (or open my laptop from sleep) it is usually slow (1sec+). This is a somewhat self solving problem after some time (like 5-10mins usually), but it is annoying and both curious as why this is happening :) Hopefully I was clear about the problem.

P.S. I tested and the difference in time from first php tag to last one is ~20 ms, so I assume it is not PHP cache that is acting up?

P.S.2. I would provide any other data needed, just not sure what to look at :) Just name it.

[image]

**UPDATE**: added Chrome's network tab.

[image]

**UPDATE**: after reinstallation of xampp the problem still persists:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncommenting the line `127.0.0.1       localhost` in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` solved the problem. The speed just jumped up incredibly. I found this advice in [here](http://cubicspot.blogspot.com/2010/07/fixing-slow-apache-on-localhost-under.html). Actually even the speed of Chrome opening other pages increased a lot o.O

Comment: You made my day Andrius! From 6sec for an ajax request to 600ms

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a screen shot of network > Timing tab of chrome developer tool for the request which takes more than a second and share it. For eg.[image]

You must analyze the time taken for each action mentioned in that tab. And also check the event trace from the speed tracer to get more information.

Comment: Added the image as requested, but there doesn't seem to be that much of the information in there, at least not much you can tell from it. And, can you be more specific about what events you want to see?

Comment: I thought it would be client side problem that is why asked you to upload it. Now it shows the problem is exactly on the server side. I guess the for first request it takes time and from the next requests, it response faster. Can you give some information on what you exactly do on the server side. Is there any db query involved. If so can you check the time it takes for the first time and next consecutive requests.I guess the first request is really getting computed and consecutive requests are using the cached result of the  previous/ first request.

Comment: Last evening while I was programming all the requests were 1 second + a few miliseconds (20...150). Sometimes, yes, first time takes longer and might even be up to 3 seconds or so, but the other times are basically stuck at 1000 + 20...150 ms. It looks like there is just a second added for something. What I have is xampp installed and I did not do any changes to it except enabling xdebug in php.ini. But again, as I said there happens to be periods of time when everything is working perfectly and the time it takes to process things is just 20...150 ms.

Comment: Moreover it fixes from time to time and then turns back to the long version of the processing the pages. My sole purpose is the speed of the website which can be achieved on localhost and this is ruining it completely. Is there a way to check what can be the reason of that delay time on some logs like apache or something else? For example, as I was writing the first version of the question it fixed itself. On the other hand today, I spent two hours programming and it didn't fix. I do not recall whether the problem existed when xdebug was not yet enabled. Will try to disable it once I get home.

Comment: Can you have a look at this http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=805 and this http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5455253

Comment: Wow! It now so seems to be the case. I will try to remove it as soon as I get home and will keep you updated.

Comment: This did not help :( However, I found out the solution and posted it as an answer. You, making so much effort trying to help me, deserve the bounty reward. Thanks so much for everything.

Comment: Good find. However I wonder! why it hasn't shown the delay in DNS Lookup in chrome under Network>Timing tab ?. Thanks for the reward

Comment: Got no idea, to be honest. Nor time to look deeper, just really glad I managed to finally solve this. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content of `save_record.php` to `<?php die(); ?>` and see what happens. I suspect it's some kind of delay in processing the save_record operation on the server-side (could be DB is the bottleneck, could be file I/O, etc).

Comment: Just checked - even with `<?php die(); ?>` it is taking over 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

save_record.php , 
what code have you written if you doing any database operation may the operation is taking to much time can you provide me the code of "save_record.php" the i can able to optimize response or can able solve your query

Comment: Please read the answer of darvids0n and comment under. I think that completely rules out any affect of database/coding issue :)